# Why we add 2 directories path in Python in Windows environment variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why we add 2  directory path in windows environment variable`C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\` ?

Is `C:\Python27\` is not sufficient ?

Any helpful answer will be appreciated !

Comment: Because the look up is not recursive? anyway I don't think this question belongs on Stackoverflow.

Comment: This makes me curious what binaries are in C:\Python27\, and what binaries are inside C:\Python27/Scripts\.

Comment: @Evert In the first one the python interpreter itself, and in the second things like `pip`, `django-admin`, `virtualenv` and such

Answer (score 1):

`sys` does not do a recursive lookup because that is wasteful. Explicitly specify the complete path to ONLY the directories/sub-directories you want to include in your `PATH`, and python will only look for modules to import there.